# What manga chapters of Minami-ke are serialized in anime and OVAs?

Tags: minami-ke

I just saw that it's still an ongoing manga, so I was wondering what chapter was the last serialized. Also, what other chapters of the manga are serialized and what's left out?

Answer (score 1):

According to [**MangaUpdates**](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=406):

> **Starts at** Volume 1, Chapter 1 (Season 1)
>
> **Ends at** Volume 6, Chapter 118 (Season 3)

These is a season 4 on top of that, but I couldn't find what it adapts.

Apparently the [**second season deviates from the manga**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minami-ke#Anime) or more accurately, includes non-manga episodes/content.

An excerpt from the link above:

> It is also different in storytelling as it uses material not from the manga

As of [**August 2014**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minami-ke#Manga), 12 tankōbon volumes of the series have been released, which as you say is still ongoing.